# How to align buttons on opposite sides of window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout

trying first time WPF user.  I read through some WPF layout docs but am not getting the hang of the layout of buttons.  I'm trying to get the layout below -- where there's a button in the lower left corner and two in the lower right.

Can this be done with a single `StackPanel`?  I tried unsuccessfully with this along with the `HorizontalAlignment` attributes of the buttons.

Is it more appropriate to be using a 1 row, 2 column grid, with each cell having a `StackPanel`?

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks!

[image: desired layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I tend to prefer doing this with a Grid, ie:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="100">b1</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="100">b2</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="100">b3</Button>
 </Grid>
```

This will cause the 2nd & 3rd columns to fit their contents, and the first to fill the rest of the space.  If you place each button in the appropriate column, you'll get that layout.  (Note that you'll likely want to adjust the sizing and margins on the buttons to get nice spacing, as well.)

Comment: You'll have to limit the width of the left most button in some way, otherwise it will stretch to fill the whole of the column.

Comment: Is this similar to using an HTML table for layout versus an HTML div?  e.g. is it considered "OK" to use grids for layout?

Comment: @LemonBeagle Grid is probably the most common layout in Xaml - this is perfectly okay to do.  I would not think of this as an HTML table.

Comment: @LemonBeagle XAML Grids are definately NOT HTML Tables.

Comment: Why not have three auto sized columns for the buttons and one star sized between that is empty?

Comment: @H.B. That's work fine, too.  If you didn't want to specify the button width's explicitly, that'd be better.  (I tend to explicitly specify the widths when making a window like this, just so they don't change size since the text is different lengths... but it's a style preference)